# How calling pick_event only once if I click on several lines in matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib, click

I'm trying to call a function on line click, in a matplotlib figure.
My issue is, if I click where multiple lines are crossing, the pick_event call several time the function. I need the function to be called only once in that case

here a minimal example:

```
 from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.lines import Line2D
import numpy as np

x = np.arange(100)
y = np.sin(x/10)

fig, ax1 = plt.subplots()
line, = ax1.plot(x, y, picker=10)
line, = ax1.plot(x, y, picker=10)
line, = ax1.plot(x, y, picker=10)

def pick_handler(event):
    print("Pick_handler called!")
    if event.mouseevent.button==1 and isinstance(event.artist, Line2D):
        print("Do the thing.")

fig.canvas.mpl_connect('pick_event', pick_handler)
plt.show()
```

if i click on the lines (3 superposed lines) the function is called three time instead of once.

Answer (score 0):

I found a way by using the coordinate where the mouse was clicked. If the previous time the function was called, the coordinate isthe same, that means the click was considered twice. I don't consider it then.

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

from matplotlib.lines import Line2D
import numpy as np

x = np.arange(100)
y = np.sin(x/10)

fig, ax1 = plt.subplots()
line, = ax1.plot(x, y, picker=10)
line, = ax1.plot(x, y, picker=10)
line, = ax1.plot(x, y, picker=10)

global previous_coord
previous_coord = (0.,0.)
def pick_handler(event):
    global previous_coord
    cuur_coord = (event.mouseevent.xdata,event.mouseevent.ydata)
    print(previous_coord)
    if event.mouseevent.button==1 and isinstance(event.artist, Line2D) and not cuur_coord == previous_coord:
        previous_coord = cuur_coord
        print("Do the thing.")

fig.canvas.mpl_connect('pick_event', pick_handler)
plt.show()
```